# Migrating free App to freemium

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm about to submit my first (free) app for the AppleStore.
I plan to make an update later with in-app purchases.
I'm not familiar with iTunes connect and I don't know yet anything about how in-app purchases works, so I'd like to know if there is anything I should be aware before submitting in order to make the future update easy/possible.

For example, I believe I should submit it as a free app, but i'm not sure i'd better make it an in-app purchase right now even if it doesn't implement purchases for now)

Many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You DO Not have to entitle an App for In-App Purchase (iAP) until you actually use it. That means you can wait and do it later when you add In-App purchases. Alternatively, you can entitle the App now (via Provisioning Portal) and not add anything until later. Either works just fine.